# What is the explanation behind this step?

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis class, the prof wrote an exercise but I didnt understand one step, it said:
For the function $f(z)=\frac{z}{z^4+4}$.
A root of $z^4+4$ is $z_o=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}=i+1$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the explanation
$$z^4 + 4 = 0$$
$$ z^4 = -4 = 4(-1 + 0i) = 4e^{i\pi}$$
$$z_0 = 4^{1/4}e^{i\pi/4} = \sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$$
$$ z_0 = \sqrt{2}(\cos(\pi/4) + i \sin(\pi/4)) = 
\sqrt{2} (1/\sqrt{2} + i/\sqrt{2})$$
$$ z_0 = 1 + i$$
I would also look into roots of unity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity to gain a better understanding of how you can find the other three roots.

**Edit:**

[Here is a resource](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/06:_Complex_Numbers/6.03:_Roots_of_Complex_Numbers#mjx-eqn-rootseqns) that will explicitly show you how to compute all 4 roots. But basically the roots split the unit circle in the complex plane into equal parts so here since $z_0$ has angle $\pi/4$ the other three roots are $z_1 = \sqrt{2}e^{i3\pi/4}$, $z_2=\sqrt{2}e^{i5\pi/4}$, and $z_3 = \sqrt{2}e^{i7\pi/4}$